# SIGABRT Error during runtime (c++)

Tags: c++, runtime-error, sigabrt

This is the skyscraper floors problem from spoj. I m getting SIGABRT when I run the code.Link for the problem is http://www.spoj.com/problems/SCRAPER/. When I run this code on my PC, it runs without any error but spoj's online judge shows SIGABRT error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct floor
{
    unsigned int floornum;
    bool calldone;
    vector <floor*> connection;
    floor()
    {
        floornum=0;
        calldone=0;
    }


};
struct elevator
{
    unsigned int x,y;
    elevator()
    {
        x=y=0;
    }
};
struct skyscrapper
{
    unsigned int f,e,a,b;
    vector <elevator> ele;

    vector <floor*> flooraddress; //this is a spoj problem


    void read()
    {
        cin>>f>>e>>a>>b;

        elevator *temp;
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<e;i++)
        {
            temp=new elevator;
            cin>>(*temp).x>>(*temp).y;
            ele.push_back(*temp);
        }
        for (unsigned int i=0;i<f;i++)
        {
            floor* tempp=new floor;
            (*tempp).floornum=i;
            flooraddress.push_back(tempp);

        }
    }
    void allotaddress()
    {

        unsigned int j,k;
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<ele.size();i++)
        {
             j=ele[i].y;
             k=ele[i].x;
            while(j<f)
            {

                if(j!=ele[i].y)
                {
                (*(flooraddress[j])).connection.push_back(flooraddress[j-k]);

                (*(flooraddress[j-k])).connection.push_back(flooraddress[j]);
                }
                j=j+k;
            }
        }
    }



};
bool flag;

bool traverse(floor* m,int destination)
    {
    if((*m).calldone==1)
    {
        return 0;
    }   
    (*m).calldone=1;    
        if((*m).floornum==destination)
        return 1;
        if((*m).connection.empty())
        return 0;

        for(int i=0;i<(*m).connection.size();i++)
        {
             flag=traverse(((*m).connection[i]),destination);
            if(flag==1)
            return flag;
        }
        return 0;
    }

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    skyscrapper iit[n];
    bool ans[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    iit[i].read();
    iit[i].allotaddress();
    ans[i]=traverse(iit[i].flooraddress[iit[i].a],iit[i].b);

}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(ans[i]==1)
    cout<<"It is possible to move the furniture."<<endl;
    else
    cout<<"The furniture cannot be moved."<<endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need error checking. If `new` returns `nullptr`, you happily dereference it.

Comment: You have a memory leak in read()

Comment: How can new return nullptr?

Comment: where exactly in read()?

Comment: @user2684957 `temp=new elevator;` there.

Comment: i have changed vector <elevator> to vector <elevator*>. so now i m storing the address of elevator. is the memory leak still der?

Comment: If the system is out of virtual memory, new, by default throws bad_alloc.  You can make it return NULL instead.

Comment: @bspikol What does return NULL mean?

Comment: You need to **always** check that your inputs where successful after reading. Quickly looking over the expressions it seems `j - k` may have funny values but it is used as an index for a vector. You seem to leak all you memory: you allocate memory but you never `delete` it. You should probably get rid of all pointers and all `new`s: C++ isn't Java or C#! You can just create values.

Comment: I have added this destructor in the struct skyscraper:

~skyscrapper()
{
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<e;i++)
  {
   delete ele[i];
  }
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<f;i++)
  {
   delete flooraddress[i];
  }
 }

//is the memory leak still there??

Comment: @NemanjaBoric plz help.